# Odd colourization for FourierParameters. UI bug?

Tags: fourier-analysis, syntax-highlighting

The Mathematica UI colourizes the FourierParameters in the following

```
Clear[x, y]
g[x_, y_] = x^2 y ;
f[x_, y_] =
 FourierSeries[x^2 y, {x, y}, {4, 4}, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 Pi}]
```

as in the following

[image: colorized input]

"Why color" on right click says it is excess arguments, but the resulting series computation matches nicely, and returns without error, so this seems like a UI colorizing bug to me.

Comment: If you look at the example given under Options in the [on-line docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FourierSeries.html), you will see the same coloring. So it must be OK, right? I mean, WRI wouldn't let a coloring error show up in their documentation would they? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I submitted this issue using the wolfram support form, and it's been accepted as a bug:

"The issue you mentioned about the coloring of the option FourierParameters in FourierSeries is indeed a Mathematica FrontEnd issue.

I will file a report based on the information provided and thank you for bringing this to our attention."